# Shell scripting not working

Tags: linux, shell, awk, scripting

```
cpu= $(mpstat | awk '$12 ~ /[0-9.]+/ { printf("%d%%",100 - $12) }' | cut -d. -f1)
```

How to refrain the output in numeric?

It's failing while comparing `%` string with numeric.

Comment: #!/bin/sh

cpu= $(mpstat | awk '$12 ~ /[0-9.]+/ { printf("%d%%",100 - $12) }' | cut -d. -f1)
if [[ "$cpu" -ge 5 ]]; then
    message="CPU Utilization is exceeded in Ec2-user Server.\nCurrent use is $cpu ."
    echo -e "$message" | mail -s "CPU Utilization monitoring" "xxx@yyy.com"
fi

Comment: Don't try to put code in comments, edit the question if you need to clarify. Use Control-k to mark code in questions.

Comment: You can't have a space after `=` in shell assignments.

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: Also, `idle` is always the last column so you can do `mpstat|awk 'p{print int(100-$NF)}/%idle/{p=1}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the `%` in the `awk` output. Add it when you're creating the email. You can also use awk's `int()` function to remove the fraction from the output, rather than piping to `cut`.

Also, make sure you don't have any spaces around the `=` in the `cpu` assignment.

```
cpu=$(mpstat | awk '$12 ~ /[0-9.]+/ {print int(100 - $12) }')
if (( $cpu > 5 ))
then mail -s "CPU Utilization monitoring" "xxx@yyy.com" <<EOF
CPU Utilization is exceeded in Ec2-user Server.
Current use is $cpu%.
EOF
fi
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, but I am not able to receive email.

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script to see a trace of all the commands.

Comment: Sounds like `awk` isn't finding any lines that match the condition `$12 ~ /[0-9.]+/`

Comment: What do you see if you do `mpstat | awk '$12 ~ /[0-9.]+/ }'`?

Comment: Thank Barmar, for you help. I got the response. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: `[[ $cpu > 5 ]]` is the wrong thing in this context -- being a string comparison, it thinks `10` is less than `5`, since `1` sorts before `5` in all locales. `(( cpu > 5 ))` or `[[ $cpu -gt 5 ]]` should be used instead, to run a numeric comparison.